# Geodesic on complex n-sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spheres

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923416/exponential-map-on-the-n-sphere), a simple formula was provided for the geodesic (and as such the exponential map) given a starting point $p$ and an initial direction $\mathbf v$ on the surface of the real unit $n$-sphere embedded in real euclidean space $\mathbb R^{n+1}$:

$$\gamma(t)=\cos(||\mathbf v||t)\mathbf p +\sin(||\mathbf v||t)\frac{\mathbf v}{||\mathbf v||}$$

Is there any equivalent for this formula for the *complex* unit $n$-sphere embedded in *complex* euclidean space $\mathbb C^{n+1}$? Does the original formula still work? Through some quick numeric investigation, the latter does not seem to be the case.

My definition of the complex unit $n$-sphere is the set of vectors in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ which admit to $\sqrt {x^\dagger x} = 1$ (so their "euclidian norm" should equal 1).

Background of the question: I am trying to apply techniques from optimizing on a regular $n$-sphere (which only require an exponential map) to the complex $n$-sphere. My local point, the gradient of the target property at that point and its tangent projection on the tangent bundle at the point are all given as vectors with complex entries. Just using the same geodesic (as pointed out above) does not cut it for some reason.

Comment: Is the complex unit $n$-sphere  not identical to the real $2n$-sphere in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}\,?$

Comment: @KurtG. do you mean that "expanding" the complex vectors such that they result in real vectors with twice the number of entries suffices? Are these new vectors then really forming a sphere? I have a hard time wrapping my head around this. Trying to implement this yielded no difference in results too.

Comment: By all means: The complex numbers $z_1,\dots, z_n$ with $|z_1|^2+\dots+|z_n|^2=1$ represent a $(2n-1)$-sphere because $|z_i|^2=x_i^2+y_i^2\,.$

Comment: This does make sense. There must be some other reason why my results do not improve when using $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @KurtG. i guess my error was in using this mapping from $\mathbb C^n$ to $\mathbb R^{2n}$ inappropriately due to other bugs in my calculations. It works now. If you want to give your suggestion again as an actual stackexchange answer i will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Glad that it works The math content is too trivial for a formal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out the in the comments, $\mathbb C^n$ is isomorph to $\mathbb R^{2n}$ which enables use of the geodesic from the question in that space.

(This answer was posted for the sole reason of marking this question as answered. If there is another way to do so without posting an official answer please let me know).

Comment: "isomorph" here should be understood as "isometric" (so that one can identify the respective unit spheres)